# Deserialize array of array using json .net

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have a json that looks like so:

```
[
["0",true,"90","0","1647537980","0","243729846566","105591923388",false,["0","0","0"],[false,"0","0","0"]],["1",true,"42","0","1646708581","1646708581","111003905","0",false,["156","94348800","1646426440"],[false,"135238559235","14754525","4"]],
["2",true,"20","0","1646708602","1646708602","54061667","0",false,["52","31449600","1646538934"],[false,"2031490329","223870","2"]],
]
```

How would one go about deserializing this json?

I tried adding [JsonConstructor] on the MyModel constructor, but it never gets called.

```
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyModel>>(json);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your JSON structure doesn't look right.  The outer square brackets should be curly braces if that is your main JSON object.

Comment: Well that is what the API I am using returns, so I do not have any control over that

Comment: Ok, then it most likely is what @Serge is suggesting.

Comment: Yes that works, but how do I map each property into a model is what I am having trouble with. For instance the first element of an array if Id, the second isActive, etc. How do I get each of those into a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a double list , so or fix json or use this code

```
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<object>>>(json);
```

The class should have at least one property. Your json doesnt' have any properties at all, so only array can be used in this case. It can be converted to the class, for example like this

```
public class MyClass
{
   public List<object> Details {get;set;}
}
var jsonParsed = JArray.Parse(json);

List<MyClass> objects = jsonParsed.Select(p => p)
.Select(x => new MyClass { Details=x.ToObject<List<object>>() }).ToList();
```

now if you want more details you have to convert array to your class,
Each element of array should get name, for example

```
public class Details
{
public Id {get; set;}
public bool IsActive {get;set}
...and so on
}
```

after this you can use this class already

```
public class MyClass
{
   public Details Details {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yup, I got that far with List<List<object>>, but how do I get each inner array into a model (MyModel in this case) which is just a placeholder at this time.